# Image mosaic with html/css fill the space

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

I'm trying to make an "image mosaic" that consists mostly of images of the same size, and some of them the double height.

They all should align neatly like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d76C.png)

But still like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9WSN.png)

I know is more "easy" do this with divs and "float:left" but i have to do with list.

Someone had i idea how can i fix this?!

Comment: Please add relevant piece of code to help you better. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What do you mean you have to do with list? Can't you just wrap them in divs? An example would really help here.

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox. You don't HAVE to use list? Unless this is a homework assignment in which case he's making you do something that's not best practice

```css
.mosaic-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 330px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.left-col, .mid-col, .right-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

.left-col .mosaic-tile:first-of-type, .right-col .mosaic-tile:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mid-col .mosaic-tile {
  height: 100%;
}

.mosaic-tile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="mosaic-container">
  <div class="left-col">
    <div class="mosaic-tile">1.1</div>
    <div class="mosaic-tile">2.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mid-col">
    <div class="mosaic-tile">1.2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-col">
    <div class="mosaic-tile">1.3</div>
    <div class="mosaic-tile">2.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will be able to implement this in a simpler and more future proof way by using CSS Grids https://learncssgrid.com/ Float based layouts are generally discouraged, similar to table based layouts.

If you are set on float based, I would create a left column div, middle column div, and right column div all float: left. Then I would place the two images in the left, tall in the middle, and last two in the right column div.